# Swift - Integer conversion to Hours/Minutes/Seconds

Tags: ios, swift

I have a (somewhat?) basic question regarding time conversions in **Swift**.

I have an integer that I would like converted into Hours / Minutes / Seconds.

**Example:** `Int = 27005` would give me:

```
7 Hours  30 Minutes 5 Seconds
```

I know how to do this in PHP, but alas, swift isn't PHP.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

Define

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(_ seconds: Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}
```

Use

```
> secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(27005)
(7,30,5)
```

or

```
let (h,m,s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(27005)
```

The above function makes use of Swift tuples to return three values at once.  You destructure the tuple using the `let (var, ...)` syntax or can access individual tuple members, if need be.

If you actually need to print it out with the words `Hours` etc then use something like this:

```
func printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(_ seconds: Int) {
  let (h, m, s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds)
  print ("\(h) Hours, \(m) Minutes, \(s) Seconds")
}
```

Note that the above implementation of `secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds()` works for `Int` arguments.  If you want a `Double` version you'll need to decide what the return values are - could be `(Int, Int, Double)` or could be `(Double, Double, Double)`.  You could try something like:

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: Double) -> (Double, Double, Double) {
  let (hr,  minf) = modf(seconds / 3600)
  let (min, secf) = modf(60 * minf)
  return (hr, min, 60 * secf)
}
```

Comment: The last value `(seconds % 3600) % 60` can be optimized to `seconds % 60`. No need to extract the hours first.

Comment: @GoZoner - i can't seem to be getting the printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds function to be working properly. This is what I have in a playground, but printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds isnt returning anything:


import UIKit


func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}
let (h,m,s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(27005)

func printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds:Int) -> () {
    let (h, m, s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds)
    println ("\(h) Hours, \(m) Minutes, \(s) Seconds")
}

Comment: `printSecondstoHoursMinutesSeconds()` doesn't return anything (see the `-> ()` return type in the function declaration).  The function prints something; which does not show up in a Playground.  If you want it to return something, say a `String` then eliminate the `println()` call and fix the function's return type.

Comment: @GoZoner - just a quick question in your syntax above. How would I declare that 27005 in a variable? I'm working on a tool right now to get my feet wet with swift. I have a constant that displays the amount of seconds (generated after my basic calculations).

let cocSeconds = cocMinutes * 60. (cocSeconds is what I want to use in place of 27005.)

I think the problem I am having is cocSeconds is a double, and in your syntax, you're using Ints. How would I go about adjusting this code to put a variable in place of 27005? Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: The solution I gave works for `Int` types because of the nature of the `/` and `%` functions.  That is `/` drops the factional part.  The same code won't work for `Double`.  Specifically 2 == 13/5 but 2.6 == 13.0/5.  Therefore you would need a different implementation for `Double`.  I've updated my answer with a note on this.

Answer (score 286):

In macOS 10.10+ / iOS 8.0+ `(NS)DateComponentsFormatter` has been introduced to create a readable string.

It considers the user's locale und language.

```
let interval = 27005

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
formatter.unitsStyle = .full

let formattedString = formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(interval))!
print(formattedString)
```

The available unit styles are `positional`, `abbreviated`, `short`, `full`, `spellOut` and `brief`.

For more information please read the [documenation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/datecomponentsformatter).

Comment: Using `formatter.unitsStyle = .positional` gives exactly what I want (which is `7:30:05`)! Best answer IMO

Comment: And you can add the zero
```
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
```

Comment: How to get the vice versa of this. That is how to convert Hour , Minute to seconds

Comment: @AngelFSyrus Simply `hours * 3600 + minutes * 60`

Comment: You might ned this if your seconds are giving less than a minute, especially in the shorter styles : `formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = [ .pad ]`

Comment: One thing to watch out for is this will crash your app if you pass a NaN or infinite time value. You should check for this before calling `formatter.string`.

Answer (score 123):

Building upon [Vadian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43890305/4475605), I wrote an extension that takes a `Double` (of which `TimeInterval` is a type alias) and spits out a string formatted as time.

```
extension Double {
  func asString(style: DateComponentsFormatter.UnitsStyle) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond]
    formatter.unitsStyle = style
    return formatter.string(from: self) ?? ""
  }
}
```

Here are what the various `DateComponentsFormatter.UnitsStyle` options look like:

```
10000.asString(style: .positional)  // 2:46:40
10000.asString(style: .abbreviated) // 2h 46m 40s
10000.asString(style: .short)       // 2 hr, 46 min, 40 sec
10000.asString(style: .full)        // 2 hours, 46 minutes, 40 seconds
10000.asString(style: .spellOut)    // two hours, forty-six minutes, forty seconds
10000.asString(style: .brief)       // 2hr 46min 40sec
```

Comment: @MaksimKniazev Usually time-oriented values are represented by `Doubles` in Swift.

Comment: @Adrian thank you for the extension. I like the .positional UnitStyle, however I would like to display ie: 9 seconds as "00:09" instead of "9", 1min 25 seconds as "01:25" instead of "1:25". I am able to achieve this calculating manually, based on Double value and I was wondering is there a way to incorporate into the extension itself? Thank you.

Comment: FYI: if you want to keep the 0s before a single digit value (or simply if the value is 0) you need to add this `formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad`.

This would give us: `3660.asString(style: .positional) // 01:01:00`

Comment: Note that DateComponentsFormatter isn't available on Linux

Comment: @Adrian ou can replace the last two lines with `return formatter.string(from: self) ?? ""`

Comment: nanosecond break in swift5

Answer (score 41):

In Swift 5:

```
    var i = 9897

    func timeString(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let hour = Int(time) / 3600
        let minute = Int(time) / 60 % 60
        let second = Int(time) % 60

        // return formated string
        return String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i", hour, minute, second)
    }
```

To call function

```
    timeString(time: TimeInterval(i))
```

Will return **02:44:57**

Comment: Superb!  Just what I required. I changed the 9897 for an Int variable and got the desired results.    Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Swift 5.3.  I send it a TimeInterval value of 217368 milliseconds and it returns 60:22:48.  217368 milliseconds is 10:02.

Comment: @SouthernYankee65 Please pass seconds, not the milliseconds. It worked for me in Swift 5.3

Answer (score 31):

I have built a mashup of existing answers to simplify everything and reduce the amount of code needed for **Swift 3**.

```
func hmsFrom(seconds: Int, completion: @escaping (_ hours: Int, _ minutes: Int, _ seconds: Int)->()) {

        completion(seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)

}

func getStringFrom(seconds: Int) -> String {

    return seconds < 10 ? "0\(seconds)" : "\(seconds)"
}
```

Usage:

```
var seconds: Int = 100

hmsFrom(seconds: seconds) { hours, minutes, seconds in

    let hours = getStringFrom(seconds: hours)
    let minutes = getStringFrom(seconds: minutes)
    let seconds = getStringFrom(seconds: seconds)

    print("\(hours):\(minutes):\(seconds)")                
}
```

Prints:

`00:01:40`

Comment: From my perspective, adding closure isn't really simplifies anything. Is there any good reason for closure?

Comment: @derpoliuk I've needed the closure for my specific needs in my app

Answer (score 28):

Here is a more structured/flexible approach: (Swift 3)

```
struct StopWatch {

    var totalSeconds: Int

    var years: Int {
        return totalSeconds / 31536000
    }

    var days: Int {
        return (totalSeconds % 31536000) / 86400
    }

    var hours: Int {
        return (totalSeconds % 86400) / 3600
    }

    var minutes: Int {
        return (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60
    }

    var seconds: Int {
        return totalSeconds % 60
    }

    //simplified to what OP wanted
    var hoursMinutesAndSeconds: (hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
        return (hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
}

let watch = StopWatch(totalSeconds: 27005 + 31536000 + 86400)
print(watch.years) // Prints 1
print(watch.days) // Prints 1
print(watch.hours) // Prints 7
print(watch.minutes) // Prints 30
print(watch.seconds) // Prints 5
print(watch.hoursMinutesAndSeconds) // Prints (7, 30, 5)
```

Having an approach like this allows the adding of convenience parsing like this:

```
extension StopWatch {

    var simpleTimeString: String {
        let hoursText = timeText(from: hours)
        let minutesText = timeText(from: minutes)
        let secondsText = timeText(from: seconds)
        return "\(hoursText):\(minutesText):\(secondsText)"
    }

    private func timeText(from number: Int) -> String {
        return number < 10 ? "0\(number)" : "\(number)"
    }
}
print(watch.simpleTimeString) // Prints 07:30:05
```

It should be noted that purely Integer based approaches don't take leap day/seconds into account. If the use case is dealing with real dates/times [Date](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/date) and [Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar) should be used.

Comment: Could you please add `month` to your implementation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use NSCalendar (Calendar) for something like that.

Comment: You could replace `return number < 10 ? "0\(number)" : "\(number)"` by using a string formatter `return String(format: "%02d", number)` which automatically adds a zero when the number is below 10

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 5:**

```
extension Int {

    func secondsToTime() -> String {

        let (h,m,s) = (self / 3600, (self % 3600) / 60, (self % 3600) % 60)

        let h_string = h < 10 ? "0\(h)" : "\(h)"
        let m_string =  m < 10 ? "0\(m)" : "\(m)"
        let s_string =  s < 10 ? "0\(s)" : "\(s)"

        return "\(h_string):\(m_string):\(s_string)"
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let seconds : Int = 119
print(seconds.secondsToTime()) // Result = "00:01:59"
```

Answer (score 18):

**Xcode 12.1. Swift 5**

DateComponentsFormatter: A formatter that creates string representations,
by using unitsStyle u can get a string as you want and mention allowedUnits.

e.g: output for unitsStyle:: for 10000 secods

1. full = "2 hours, 46 minutes, 49 seconds"
2. positional = "2:46:40"
3. abbreviated = "2h 46m 40s"
4. spellOut =  "two hours, forty-six minutes, forty seconds”
5. short = "2hr,46 min,40 sec"
6. brief = "2hr 46min 40sec"

Easy to use:

```
 let time = convertSecondsToHrMinuteSec(seconds: 10000)


func convertSecondsToHrMinuteSec(seconds:Int) -> String{
     let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
     formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
     formatter.unitsStyle = .full
    
     let formattedString = formatter.string(from:TimeInterval(seconds))!
     print(formattedString)
     return formattedString
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

Swift 4

```
func formatSecondsToString(_ seconds: TimeInterval) -> String {
    if seconds.isNaN {
        return "00:00"
    }
    let Min = Int(seconds / 60)
    let Sec = Int(seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d", Min, Sec)
}
```

Comment: What is truncatingRemainder ? Xcode does not recognize it for me.

Comment: you can read more about truncatingRemainder [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2885641-truncatingremainder)

Answer (score 13):

Here is another simple implementation in Swift3.

```
func seconds2Timestamp(intSeconds:Int)->String {
   let mins:Int = intSeconds/60
   let hours:Int = mins/60
   let secs:Int = intSeconds%60

   let strTimestamp:String = ((hours<10) ? "0" : "") + String(hours) + ":" + ((mins<10) ? "0" : "") + String(mins) + ":" + ((secs<10) ? "0" : "") + String(secs)
   return strTimestamp
}
```

Answer (score 12):

SWIFT 3.0 solution based roughly on the one above using extensions.

```
extension CMTime {
  var durationText:String {
    let totalSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(self)
    let hours:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 86400) / 3600)
    let minutes:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60)
    let seconds:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))

    if hours > 0 {
        return String(format: "%i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    } else {
        return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
    }

  }
}
```

Use it with AVPlayer calling it like this?

```
 let dTotalSeconds = self.player.currentTime()
 playingCurrentTime = dTotalSeconds.durationText
```

Answer (score 8):

I had answered [to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59804193/2229783), however you don't need to display milliseconds in the result. Hence my solution requires iOS 10.0, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0 or macOS 10.12.

You should call `func convertDurationUnitValueToOtherUnits(durationValue:durationUnit:smallestUnitDuration:)` from the answer that I already mentioned here:

```
let secondsToConvert = 27005
let result: [Int] = convertDurationUnitValueToOtherUnits(
    durationValue: Double(secondsToConvert),
    durationUnit: .seconds,
    smallestUnitDuration: .seconds
)
print("\(result[0]) hours, \(result[1]) minutes, \(result[2]) seconds") // 7 hours, 30 minutes, 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 7):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48373046/4441676) of @r3dm4n was great. However, I also needed hour in it. Just in case someone else needed too here it is:

```
func formatSecondsToString(_ seconds: TimeInterval) -> String {
    if seconds.isNaN {
        return "00:00:00"
    }
    let sec = Int(seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
    let min = Int(seconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60)
    let hour = Int(seconds / 3600)
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5 & String Response, In presentable format**

```
public static func secondsToHoursMinutesSecondsStr (seconds : Int) -> String {
      let (hours, minutes, seconds) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: seconds);
      var str = hours > 0 ? "\(hours) h" : ""
      str = minutes > 0 ? str + " \(minutes) min" : str
      str = seconds > 0 ? str + " \(seconds) sec" : str
      return str
  }

public static func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
        return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
 }
```

**Usage:**

```
print(secondsToHoursMinutesSecondsStr(seconds: 20000)) // Result = "5 h 33 min 20 sec"
```

Answer (score 3):

According to **GoZoner** answer I have wrote an Extension to get the **time formatted** according to the hours, minute, and seconds:

```
extension Double {

    func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds () -> (Int?, Int?, Int?) {
        let hrs = self / 3600
        let mins = (self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600)) / 60
        let seconds = (self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:3600)).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:60)
        return (Int(hrs) > 0 ? Int(hrs) : nil , Int(mins) > 0 ? Int(mins) : nil, Int(seconds) > 0 ? Int(seconds) : nil)
    }

    func printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds () -> String {

        let time = self.secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds()

        switch time {
        case (nil, let x? , let y?):
            return "\(x) min \(y) sec"
        case (nil, let x?, nil):
            return "\(x) min"
        case (let x?, nil, nil):
            return "\(x) hr"
        case (nil, nil, let x?):
            return "\(x) sec"
        case (let x?, nil, let z?):
            return "\(x) hr \(z) sec"
        case (let x?, let y?, nil):
            return "\(x) hr \(y) min"
        case (let x?, let y?, let z?):
            return "\(x) hr \(y) min \(z) sec"
        default:
            return "n/a"
        }
    }
}

let tmp = 3213123.printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds() // "892 hr 32 min 3 sec"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I use for my Music Player in Swift 4+. I am converting seconds **Int** to readable *String* format

```
extension Int {
    var toAudioString: String {
        let h = self / 3600
        let m = (self % 3600) / 60
        let s = (self % 3600) % 60
        return h > 0 ? String(format: "%1d:%02d:%02d", h, m, s) : String(format: "%1d:%02d", m, s)
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
print(7903.toAudioString)
```

Output: `2:11:43`

Answer (score 3):

### Latest Code: XCode 10.4 Swift 5

```
extension Int {
    func timeDisplay() -> String {
        return "\(self / 3600):\((self % 3600) / 60):\((self % 3600) % 60)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From @Gamec answer

```swift
typealias CallDuration = Int

extension CallDuration {
    func formatedString() -> String? {
        let hours = self / 3600
        let minutes = (self / 60) % 60
        let seconds = self % 60
        if hours > 0 { return String(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d", hours, minutes, seconds) }
        return String(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d", minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let duration: CallDuration = 3000
duration.formatedString() // 50 minute
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way imho:

```
let hours = time / 3600
let minutes = (time / 60) % 60
let seconds = time % 60
return String(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d", hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: It may be `ld` for double instead of `d` for int.

Comment: @NikeKov `%ld` is for long int. Use `%f` for double and float.

Answer (score 1):

`NSTimeInterval` is `Double` do do it with extension. Example:

```
extension Double {

    var formattedTime: String {

        var formattedTime = "0:00"

        if self > 0 {

            let hours = Int(self / 3600)
            let minutes = Int(truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60)

            formattedTime = String(hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + String(minutes) : String(minutes))
        }

        return formattedTime
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

convert a number into time as a string

```
func convertToHMS(number: Int) -> String {
  let hour    = number / 3600;
  let minute  = (number % 3600) / 60;
  let second = (number % 3600) % 60 ;
  
  var h = String(hour);
  var m = String(minute);
  var s = String(second);
  
  if h.count == 1{
      h = "0\(hour)";
  }
  if m.count == 1{
      m = "0\(minute)";
  }
  if s.count == 1{
      s = "0\(second)";
  }
  
  return "\(h):\(m):\(s)"
}
print(convertToHMS(number:3900))
```

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created a closure for this (in Swift 3).

```
let (m, s) = { (secs: Int) -> (Int, Int) in
        return ((secs % 3600) / 60, (secs % 3600) % 60) }(299)
```

This will give m = 4 and s = 59. So you can format that as you wish. You may of course want to add hours as well, if not more information.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 I'm using this extension

```
 extension Double {

    func stringFromInterval() -> String {

        let timeInterval = Int(self)

        let millisecondsInt = Int((self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1)) * 1000)
        let secondsInt = timeInterval % 60
        let minutesInt = (timeInterval / 60) % 60
        let hoursInt = (timeInterval / 3600) % 24
        let daysInt = timeInterval / 86400

        let milliseconds = "\(millisecondsInt)ms"
        let seconds = "\(secondsInt)s" + " " + milliseconds
        let minutes = "\(minutesInt)m" + " " + seconds
        let hours = "\(hoursInt)h" + " " + minutes
        let days = "\(daysInt)d" + " " + hours

        if daysInt          > 0 { return days }
        if hoursInt         > 0 { return hours }
        if minutesInt       > 0 { return minutes }
        if secondsInt       > 0 { return seconds }
        if millisecondsInt  > 0 { return milliseconds }
        return ""
    }
}
```

useage

```
// assume myTimeInterval = 96460.397    
myTimeInteval.stringFromInterval() // 1d 2h 47m 40s 397ms
```

Answer (score 0):

[neek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41749037/2224321) isn't correct.

here's the correct version

```
func seconds2Timestamp(intSeconds:Int)->String {
   let mins:Int = (intSeconds/60)%60
   let hours:Int = intSeconds/3600
   let secs:Int = intSeconds%60

   let strTimestamp:String = ((hours<10) ? "0" : "") + String(hours) + ":" + ((mins<10) ? "0" : "") + String(mins) + ":" + ((secs<10) ? "0" : "") + String(secs)
   return strTimestamp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be convert seconds to date and take the components i.e seconds, minutes and hour from date itself.
This solution has limitation only till 23:59:59