# Getting a readable time from timeIntervalSinceDate in swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

I'm trying to figure out how to get a readable time amount from timeIntervalSinceDate. Right now I have an NSDate with key "punchInTime" stored in NSUserDefaults, but I don't know how to get a readable time back when I want to find the difference between the stored NSDate "punchInTime" and the current time. I have:

```
var totalWorkTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(punchInTime)
```

I'd like to interpolate "totalWorkTime" into a string to have readable time amounts.

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift - Integer conversion to Hours/Minutes/Seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794703/swift-integer-conversion-to-hours-minutes-seconds)

Comment: Do you want to know Hour minutes and seconds or the total of the highest unit like 10 seconds, 10 minutes, 10 hours, 10 days and so on?

Answer (score 8):

Fix your syntax. It should be:

```
var totalWorkTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(punchInTime)
```

Note the parenthesis after `NSDate`. If you do not use parenthesis, and you try to treat `totalWorkTime` as an NSTimeInterval you will get the error `Cannot invoke [operator] with an argument list of type ...`

[image]

You can get a better error message if you specify the type in the variable assignment. The error is `(x) -> y is not convertible to y`

[image]

Swift is a functional language. Without the parenthesis after `NSDate` then `totalWorkTime` is not a symbol for a mere NSTimeInterval type, but rather it is a symbol for a **function** that takes an NSDate and returns a NSTimeInterval. This syntax in a playground shows:

[image]

Other than what I wrote above, zisoft is correct about this question (almost) being a duplicate. The other minor exception is that this question is asking about a `Double` (`NSTimeInterval`) type and the earlier question is asking about `Int`.