# Convert TimeInterval To String <del>String To Time Interval</del>

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I have a `TimeInterval` I had to turn it into a `String` so it could be added to the `Dictionary` that gets passed from Apple Watch to iPhone via `WatchConnectivity`.

Now that I **have the `String` on the iPhone, I need to turn it back into a `TimeInterval`**, but I can't seem to figure that out.

(I need to display this in a `UILabel` that shows the duration of the workout session.)

Any ideas?

*For Example*

**Watch**:

00:15:15 (hours, minutes, seconds) turns into "915.012948989868"

```swift
let myDouble = computeDurationOfWorkout(withEvents: hkWorkout?.workoutEvents, startDate: hkWorkout?.startDate, endDate: hkWorkout?.endDate)
let myDoubleString = String(myDouble)
durationVariableString = myDoubleString
```

**iPhone**:

Need to turn "915.012948989868" back into 00:15:15

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794703/swift-integer-conversion-to-hours-minutes-seconds

Comment: Your question is very confusing. It seems you already have code to convert a `TimeInterval` to a string in the format hh:mm:ss. It seems you already have code to convert the string back into a `TimeInterval` (double). What exactly are you asking for help with?

Comment: @toddg I will check out that link, thanks!

Comment: @rmaddy I don't see that I have code to convert the String back to a `TimeInterval`, which is what I'm looking for.  But maybe I'm mistaken and you see something that I am totally missing, which could definitely be the case. Are you talking about the line `let myDouble = computeDurationOfWorkout(withEvents: hkWorkout?.workoutEvents, startDate: hkWorkout?.startDate, endDate: hkWorkout?.endDate)`? That part pulls from HealthKit, but when I'm on the iPhone I'm just trying to pull from a `String` that was passed to me.

Comment: Do you want to just convert  915 to 00:15:15 ?

Comment: Yes, I assumed your `computeDurationOfWorkout` was your code for converting the string back to a double. Especially since your question states that on the Watch you convert the string into the double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `calendar.dateComponents` you can convert `915` to  `00:15:15`

```
func stringFromTimeInterval (interval: String) -> String {
        let endingDate = Date()
        if let timeInterval = TimeInterval(interval) {
            let startingDate = endingDate.addingTimeInterval(-timeInterval)
            let calendar = Calendar.current

            var componentsNow = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: startingDate, to: endingDate)
            if let hour = componentsNow.hour, let minute = componentsNow.minute, let seconds = componentsNow.second {
                return "\(hour):\(minute):\(seconds)"
            } else {
                return "00:00:00"
            }

        } else {
            return "00:00:00"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This isn't quite the exact fit, because I need to pass in a `String` as an argument, not a `TimeInterval` as an argument.  And then I need to return a `TimeInterval`, instead of return a `String`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You need a function in which you pass 00:15:15 and it will return 915 ?

Comment: A function where I pass in a `String` "915.012948989868", and get back a `TimeInterval` "00:15:15".  Like `func timeIntervalFromString (string: String) -> TimeInterval` or something?

Comment: 00:15:15 that is not a TimeInterval, **TimeInterval is always specified in seconds**, also you can convert TimeInterval to String in the above function

Comment: "915.012948989868" is a `TimeInterval` as String though. Which is what I have. So I need to convert that String to a TimeInterval first though right? And then convert that TimeInterval into 00:15:15, right?

Comment: Yes you need to convert String to TimeInterval

Comment: Thanks I'll do that!

Comment: @SRMR updated my answer, the function will take string now and return you string

Comment: This solution has 1 flaw, but a simple one in the formatting - 0's are not padded out. To fix that you need some old fashion String(format:) calls. I implemented this as a TimeInterval extension - see below for my sample

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as an extension to TimeInterval. Also this version correctly handles minutes / seconds < 10 by padding them.

```
extension TimeInterval {
    var formatted: String {
        let endingDate = Date()
        let startingDate = endingDate.addingTimeInterval(-self)
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        var componentsNow = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: startingDate, to: endingDate)
        if let hour = componentsNow.hour, let minute = componentsNow.minute, let seconds = componentsNow.second {
            return "\(String(format: "%02d", hour)):\(String(format: "%02d", minute)):\(String(format: "%02d", seconds))"
        } else {
            return "00:00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

and handle the String -> TimeInterval conversion inline.

```
TimeInterval(intervalAsString).formatted
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of turning the time interval into a string, instead turn it into an NSNumber that can be added to the Dictionary. An NSTimeInterval is simply a double, so you can cast it to and from a double easily.

```
let timeInterval: TimeInterval = 915.012948989868

let dict = ["TimeIneterval": NSNumber(value: timeInterval)]

if let extractedTimeInterval: TimeInterval = dict["TimeIneterval"] as? TimeInterval {

    print(extractedTimeInterval)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will give this a try.  Once I pass the `NSNumber` via the Dictionary to the iPhone, once I've got the `NSNumber` on the iPhone would I just need to convert it back to a `TimeInterval` then?

Answer (score 0):

Found simple solution with native `DateComponentsFormatter`:

```
func formatted(interval: TimeInterval) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropLeading // drop leading zero values
    return formatter.string(from: timeInterval)
}
```