# Convert dates to multiple formats with SwiftDate

Tags: swift, time

Is it possible to convert a date, say it is in minutes to another format using [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) library? For example:

> 77 minutes = 1 hour, 17 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use [this](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo) library? You can import `NSDateTimeAgo.bundle` and `NSDate+Extension.swift`. And to convert your timestamp to lets say 1 hour, 17 minutes you can do like this:

```
let timestamp = //timestamp or time
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp!)
let timeAgo = date.timeAgo
print(timeAgo)
```

I am suggesting you this because it is more lightweight. And if you do not need the "ago" then you can remove those from `NSDateTimeAgo.string` file.

But you can also do it without any library like this eg with seconds:

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}

func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds:Int) -> () {
    let (h, m, s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds: seconds)
    print ("\(h) Hours, \(m) Minutes, \(s) Seconds")
}
secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: 3000)// it would print 0 Hours, 50 Minutes, 0 Seconds
```

You can also suit it for your needs(this code is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26794841/3848797) answer).