# How separate a xml string into tuple?

Tags: ios, swift, xml

I want to convert an XML string into a tuple.

```
var responseXml =
"""
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tmweb>
<booking type='come' time='71102' persnr='9999' name='Test' firstname='Max' title='Mr.'/>
</tmweb>
"""

responseXml.removeFirst(39)                                          // Remove the beginning of the XML
responseXml.removeLast(11)                                           // Remove the end of the XML
responseXml = responseXml.replacingOccurrences(of:" ", with: ";")   // Replace empty place with ;
responseXml = responseXml.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "\"")    // Replace ' to "
responseXml = responseXml.replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: ": ")    // Replace = to :(space)
```

Temporary output:

```
"type: "come";time: "71102";persnr: "9999";name: "Test";firstname: "Max";title: "Mr."\n"
```

At the moment I only have the whole string as with the replacements as a UIAlert

My next steps:

I want to convert the seconds (71102) to readable time format like 19:45:22

```
func secs2time (_ seconds : Int) -> (Int,Int,Int) {
    return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}
```

At the moment it's hard to find a good solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To handle the `xml` you will need to user `NSXMLParser`. Here are two sites that can help you.

http://leaks.wanari.com/2016/08/24/xml-parsing-swift/
https://medium.com/@lucascerro/understanding-nsxmlparser-in-swift-xcode-6-3-1-7c96ff6c65bc

Here is a little example:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/website-with-xml")
var xmlParser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)
xmlParser.delegate = self
xmlParser.parse()

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: NSDictionary!) {
   println("Element's name is \(elementName)")
   println("Element's attributes are \(attributeDict)")
}
```

For the time conversion you can found it on other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794703/swift-integer-conversion-to-hours-minutes-seconds/26794841#26794841) in Stackoverflow:

> Define

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
  return (seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}
```

> Use
>
> secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(27005)
>       (7,30,5)
>
> or

```
let (h,m,s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(27005)
```

> The above function makes use of Swift tuples to return three values at
>   once.  You destructure the tuple using the `let (var, ...)` syntax or
>   can access individual tuple members, if need be.
>
> If you actually need to print it out with the words `Hours` etc then
>   use something like this:

```
func printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds:Int) -> () {
  let (h, m, s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds)
  print ("\(h) Hours, \(m) Minutes, \(s) Seconds")
}
```

> Note that the above implementation of `secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds()`
>   works for `Int` arguments.  If you want a `Double` version you'll need
>   to decide what the return values are - could be `(Int, Int, Double)`
>   or could be `(Double, Double, Double)`.  You could try something like:

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Double) -> (Double, Double, Double) {
  let (hr,  minf) = modf (seconds / 3600)
  let (min, secf) = modf (60 * minf)
  return (hr, min, 60 * secf)
}
```