# How to sum array of time Duration Which is in string format

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i Have an array of strings with the following format,

`let sample_array = ["05:30","06:20","04:20","09:40"]`

When after we converted all `string` to `DATE` format ,How can we find the total time from this array.

Comment: What do you mean by "total time"?

Comment: array is like ["04:30" , "04:00"] , So the total hour 08:30. like that @AhmadF

Comment: Can u just explain how to add the duration @Moritz

Comment: what you have tried yet???

Comment: i just tried to convert the strings to date format and tried @YagneshDobariya

Comment: @Thug. show some code related to it.

Comment: Your question is not very clear and currently shows no attempt or research. please add some code and explain what the issue is with it. questions should not need so many comments for clarification

Comment: So to make sure that I got what are you asking about, If we have ["20:40" , "20:40"], the output should be: 41:20, correct?

Comment: yes like that @AhmadF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can skip converting string to date for achieving your desired output:

```
let sample_array = ["05:30","06:20","04:20","09:40"]
var hours:Int = 0
var minutes:Int = 0
for timeString in sample_array {
    let components = timeString.components(separatedBy: ":")
    let hourComp = Int(components.first ?? "0") ?? 0
    let minComp = Int(components.last ?? "0") ?? 0
    hours += hourComp
    minutes += minComp
}
hours += minutes/60
minutes = minutes%60
let hoursString = hours > 9 ? hours.description : "0\(hours)"
let minsString = minutes > 9 ? minutes.description : "0\(minutes)"
let totalTime = hoursString+":"+minsString
```

Comment: it's worked. sorry i can't upvote your answer. atleast 15 reputaion needed for that. =D , thanks @Puneet

Comment: @Thug__ you should accept it as valid answer if it woks for you

Answer (score 2):

For your case, I would suggest to handle it without looking at it as dates. You could get your desired result by implementing a function as:

```
func getTotalTime(_ array: [String]) -> String {
    // getting the summation of minutes and seconds
    var minutesSummation = 0
    var secondsSummation = 0

    array.forEach { string in
        minutesSummation += Int(string.components(separatedBy: ":").first ?? "0")!
        secondsSummation += Int(string.components(separatedBy: ":").last ?? "0")!
    }

    // converting seconds to minutes
    let minutesInSeconds = secondsToMinutes(seconds: secondsSummation).0
    let restOfSeconds = secondsToMinutes(seconds: secondsSummation).1

    return "\(minutesSummation + minutesInSeconds):\(restOfSeconds)"
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794703/swift-integer-conversion-to-hours-minutes-seconds
func secondsToMinutes (seconds : Int) -> (Int, Int) {
    return ((seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 3600) % 60)
}
```

Therefore:

```
let array = ["20:40" , "20:40"]
let result = getTotalTime(array)
print(result) // 41:20
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question and comments it seems that you are trying to calculate the total time (in hours and minutes) from the given array.

```
let sample_array = ["05:30","06:20","04:20","09:40"]

func getTime(arr: [String]) -> Int {

  var total = 0
  for obj in arr {

      let comp = obj.split(separator: ":")

      var hours = 0
      var minutes = 0
      if let hr = comp.first, let h = Int(String(hr)) {
        hours = h * 60
      }

      if let mn = comp.last, let min = Int(String(mn)) {
        minutes = min
      }

      total += hours
      total += minutes

    }
    return total

}

let totalTime = getTime(arr: sample_array)
print(totalTime)

let hours = totalTime/60
let minutes = totalTime%60
print("\(hours) hours and \(minutes) minutes")
```

You can further calculates days, month and year also.

I hope it is what you want.