# Convert Minutes to HH:MM:SS - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, decimal

I have some text fields in an array. HH:MM:SS. I'm having two issues, one is when one of the fields is left blank, the app crashes and I want it to just read as "0" if blank. Second, I use below to convert HH:MM:SS to Minutes. I do 0:18:30 and the math below to decimal comes out to 18.5

Now how would I convert this back to HH:MM:SS? `array[0]` is hours, `array[1]` is minutes, `array[2]` is seconds.

```
stepOne = (Float(array[0])! * 60) + Float(array[1])! + (Float(array[2])! / 60)
```

Comment: Why are you fildding around with all these multiplications, additions, force unwraps? Just use `DateFormatter`.

Comment: I think this will help you. Take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794703/swift-integer-conversion-to-hours-minutes-seconds/43890305)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to calculate the number of seconds instead of number of minutes. Using the reduce method just multiply the first element by 3600 and then divide the multiplier by 60 after each iteration. Next you can use `DateComponentsFormatter` to display the resulting seconds time interval using `.positional` units style to the user:

```
let array = [0,18,30]
var n = 3600
let seconds = array.reduce(0) {
    defer { n /= 60 }
    return $0 + $1 * n
}
```

---

```
let dcf = DateComponentsFormatter()
dcf.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
dcf.unitsStyle = .positional
dcf.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
let string = dcf.string(from: TimeInterval(seconds))  // "00:18:30"
```

Comment: How can I insert that back into my array of TextFields which are set up as HH MM SS? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your actual code with the issues you are facing?

Comment: Thank you so much! This help figure about 85% of the solution and I figured it out from there to make it work in my app the way I wanted. Appreciate it, have a good weekend.